# determining if there are equal number of a and b terms in a List using prolog

Tags: prolog

The problem states: Define a relation, equal_a_b(L), in Prolog, where equal_a_b(L) is *true* if L contains an equal number of **a** and **b** terms.

I wrote code to count the number of a terms and b terms and check to see if a==b.  If a===b is false then the program should output **no**. However, when i test my code, it outputs yes and i dont know why.

Here's the code:

```
equal_a_b(L):-
   eqab(L, A, B),
   eqabn(A, B).

eqab([], 0, 0).
eqab([a|L], X, Y):- eqab(L, Z, A), X is Z + 1, Y is A + 0.
eqab([b|L], X, Y):- eqab(L, Z, A), X is Z + 0, Y is A + 1.
eqab([C|L], X, Y):- eqab(L, Z, A), X is Z + 0, Y is A + 0. 

eqabn(A, B):- A==B.
```

Heres the trace program for example (equal_a_b([a]). which should output no:

```
| ?- trace, equal_a_b([a]).
The debugger will first creep -- showing everything (trace)
  1    1  Call: equal_a_b([a]) ? 
  2    2  Call: eqab([a],_85,_86) ? 
  3    3  Call: eqab([],_110,_111) ? 
  3    3  Exit: eqab([],0,0) ? 
  4    3  Call: _138 is 0+1 ? 
  4    3  Exit: 1 is 0+1 ? 
  5    3  Call: _166 is 0+0 ? 
  5    3  Exit: 0 is 0+0 ? 
  2    2  Exit: eqab([a],1,0) ? 
  6    2  Call: eqabn(1,0) ? 
  7    3  Call: 1==0 ? 
  7    3  Fail: 1==0 ? 
  6    2  Fail: eqabn(1,0) ? 
  2    2  Redo: eqab([a],1,0) ? n

(10 ms) yes
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks.

Comment: `[a]` will match `[C|L]` as well as `[a|L]`. You will want to ensure that `C \= a` and `C \= b` in your last clause. Otherwise, it will cause, `eqab([a], 0, 0)` to be true.

Comment: For brevity, you can say, `eqab([a|L], X, A) :- eqab(L, Z, A), X is Z + 1.` instead of `eqab([a|L], X, Y):- eqab(L, Z, A), X is Z + 1, Y is A + 0.`. Similarly for your `eqab([b|L],...)` clause.

Answer (score 2):

```
equal_a_b(Xs) :-
   equals_a_b__n(Xs, 0).

equals_a_b__n([], 0).
equals_a_b__n([C|Cs], N0) :-
   char_n_(C, N0,N1),
   equals_a_b__n(Cs, N1).

char_n_(C, N, N) :-
   dif(C,a),
   dif(C,b).
char_n_(a, N0, N) :-
   N is N0 + 1.
char_n_(b, N0, N) :-
   N is N0 - 1.
```

This solution is a true relation, you can even ask

> Tell me all lists that contain the same number of characters `a` and `b`.

```
?- length(Xs, N), equal_a_b(Xs).
   Xs = [], N = 0
;  Xs = [_A], N = 1,
   dif(_A,a), dif(_A,b)
;  Xs = [_A,_B], N = 2,
   dif(_A,a), dif(_A,b), dif(_B,a), dif(_B,b)
;  Xs = [a,b], N = 2
;  Xs = [b,a], N = 2
;  Xs = [_A,_B,_C], N = 3,
   dif(_A,a), dif(_A,b), dif(_B,a), dif(_B,b), dif(_C,a), dif(_C,b)
;  Xs = [_A,a,b], N = 3,
   dif(_A,a), dif(_A,b)
;  Xs = [_A,b,a], N = 3,
   dif(_A,a), dif(_A,b)
;  Xs = [a,_A,b], N = 3,
   dif(_A,a), dif(_A,b)
;  Xs = [a,b,_A], N = 3,
   dif(_A,a), dif(_A,b)
;  Xs = [b,_A,a], N = 3,
   dif(_A,a), dif(_A,b)
;  Xs = [b,a,_A], N = 3,
   dif(_A,a), dif(_A,b)
;  ... .
```

And then, it is also more efficient in current implementations. In fact, in the case of a ground list `Xs` with length *l*, it only requires space proportional to log *l*, whereas your and @lurker 's solution require space that is proportional to *l*.

Answer (score 0):

as lurker noted, your program must avoid the 'catchall' rule when it 'sees' an 'a' or a 'b'. The simpler patch I can think of: commit the choices with cuts. Here is one:

```
...
eqab([a|L], X, Y):- eqab(L, Z, A), !, X is Z + 1, Y is A + 0.
...
```

but the whole would be simpler if you 'invert' the control flow: count down and check, when the list becomes empty, if counts match.